# Size of instance of class in c++

Tags: c++, performance-testing

I am trying to find a proper way to measure the size of objects in c++. Because previously I was using Java I was always using [the following library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.carrotsearch/java-sizeof) which iterates over the references of an object recursively and calculates the size in KB or in MB. I also saw that there is the possibility to use sizeof, however, this is not suitable for me since for an object it returns always the same size, no matter the data stored inside of it. Could you maybe provide some information or a library which measures the size of objects for performance testing or explain to me if I am mistaken for sizeof in C++?

EDIT:
I am trying to Measure the size of an instance of a class. 
I am measuring an instance of a class which includes an array. No matter the size of the array the sizeof operator returns 24 as a result. I am trying to compare two methods two types of structures and report on the size saving with the second one, or actually compare which method results in a larger size.

Comment: Could it be that you're simply using `sizeof()` wrongly?

Comment: What do you mean by "object"? An instance of a class or structure? Why do you need the size? What is the problem you're trying to solve? And for some specific "object", what is the size you expect, and what is the size you get?

Comment: Yes as I mentioned maybe I am using it wrongly

Comment: i doubt there is a tool that does what you are aiming for. Consider `struct foo { int * f; }` there is no way to know whether the data stored at `f` belongs to `foo` or not, also you cannot know if `f` points to a single `int` or to an array of certain size. To know the size of an object `sizeof` is the right tool

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just made an edit I hope it helps

Comment: Doing `sizeof` on a pointer will give you the size of the *pointer itself*, not what it might point to. The size of a pointer will typically be 4 on 32-bit systems and 8 on 64-bit systems. Also remember that structures and classes can contain *padding* between members, or after the last member, and that is counted with `sizeof`. And if you have virtual functions then the `sizeof` operator could include the data needed for the virtual dispatch table.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude still is there a way to measure the size of an instance and the things that it points to? For example for a simple array in Java if the array is empty the sizeof maven operator will give small number, then the size will increase with the number of elements included within the array

Comment: For pointers it's not possible, since for an "array" it only points to the first element and there's no information about the size of the "array". You simple have to keep track of it yourself (or better yet use `std::vector`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general way to get the total memory usage of an object in C++ including dynamically allocated memory (consider two objects, both of which have a pointer to the same third object.  Should the third object be counted twice?).

If you wish to track memory usage in your application, then you can override `operator new` and/or create your own allocator for use with STL functions.

Comment: could you maybe provide a reference or a simple usage of how to do that? Thank you for the useful answer